# How to assign value to public variable in asp.net at runtime?

Tags: asp.net

```
Public Class index
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim arr(9) As Integer

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
arr(0) = 23
End Sub

Protected Sub bntInsert_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles bntInsert.Click
arr(0) = 999
End Sub   

Protected Sub bntShow_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles bntShow.Click
txtid.Text = arr(0).ToString
End Sub
End Class
```

The result is that when I click on bntInsert and after bntShow it still show value "23" in txtid. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

1: asp.net is stateless.
2: check for post-back events?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 if page.isPostBack then
arr(0) = 23
end if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because every button click eventually call page_load first. I guess you are trying to use public variables to to keep the values but you need to understand that a particular variable is valid only for a specific request. The variable will be lost for every subsequent requests including button clicks (which is a post back).

You might want to keep the arr in a session variable to save its value between round trips.

Comment: Thank for your comment Apurv Gupta!